# Write CSV file decrease it/s during processing

Tags: python, performance, csv, optimization, export

I have a CSV file where I want to modify values inside. This file has more than 1 millions lines.

At the begiging of the file, the script go at `5000 lines per seconds`, but then it decrease to `400 lines per seconds`.

**I would like to know why it is slowing down and how to improve this script performances** ?

```
txt = ""
data = open(path + "_mag.csv").readlines()
i = 0
for line in tqdm.tqdm(data):
    if i == 0:
        txt += line + "\n"
        i += 1
        continue
    values = line.split(";")
    for j, value in enumerate(mag_rotated[i-1]):  # 15 values in float type
        index = j + 5
        values[index] = str(value)
    new_line = ";".join(values)
    txt += new_line + "\n"
    i += 1
```

Here is a small lines examples of data:

```
Timestamp [µs];Temp ADC1 [°C];Temp ADC2 [°C];Temp ADC3 [°C];Temp ADC4 [°C];X0 [µT];Y0 [µT];Z0 [µT];X1 [µT];Y1 [µT];Z1 [µT];X2 [µT];Y2 [µT];Z2 [µT];X3 [µT];Y3 [µT];Z3 [µT];X4 [µT];Y4 [µT];Z4 [µT];unused;X5 [µT];Y5 [µT];Z5 [µT];X6 [µT];Y6 [µT];Z6 [µT];X7 [µT];Y7 [µT];Z7 [µT];X8 [µT];Y8 [µT];Z8 [µT];X9 [µT];Y9 [µT];Z9 [µT];unused
911532093;30.563;30.313;;;-1.62919885e+01;1.86305991e+01;3.93283914e+01;-1.59370440e+01;1.88661384e+01;3.93722822e+01;-1.60104993e+01;1.89392587e+01;3.93954596e+01;-1.63657738e+01;1.86798405e+01;3.93386700e+01;-1.65630085e+01;1.78254986e+01;3.95608333e+01;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
911533093;30.563;30.313;;;-1.62927678e+01;1.86261966e+01;3.93056706e+01;-1.59385424e+01;1.88634411e+01;3.93504949e+01;-1.60110385e+01;1.89362330e+01;3.93737558e+01;-1.63657738e+01;1.86764223e+01;3.93170219e+01;-1.65643876e+01;1.78232520e+01;3.95398268e+01;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
911534093;30.563;30.313;;;-1.62899203e+01;1.86278438e+01;3.93394221e+01;-1.59340472e+01;1.88623921e+01;3.93840899e+01;-1.60095108e+01;1.89366524e+01;3.94075406e+01;-1.63627492e+01;1.86763323e+01;3.93510360e+01;-1.65617493e+01;1.78224132e+01;3.95712317e+01;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

For context: my script aim to replace theses 15 values:
`X0 [µT] Y0 [µT] Z0 [µT] X1 [µT] Y1 [µT] Z1 [µT] X2 [µT] Y2 [µT] Z2 [µT] X3 [µT] Y3 [µT] Z3 [µT] X4 [µT] Y4 [µT] Z4 [µT]`

Comment: you (re)create a potentially large string over and over again by using `txt += new_line + "\n"` Try appending `new_line` into a list `new_lines` then creating the string once after the loop via `txt = "\n".join(new_lines).

Comment: What does `mag_rotated` look like? Do you need to write to the same file or can you write to a temp file then rename the temps file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there are two reasons for the slow down.

1. is because you are trying to store all the modified data into a single string variable `txt`.
2. You are reading the entire CSV file into memory at once with `readlines()`, which can consume a lot of memory because the file is large.

You should write directly to the output file instead of storing it all in memory.

A good way to do that is to open two files, the input and output files. Then read lines from the input file one at a time and write the modified line directly to the output file

```
import tqdm

with open(path + "_mag.csv", "r") as fin, open(path + "_mag_modified.csv", "w") as fout:
    for i, line in enumerate(tqdm.tqdm(fin)):
        if i == 0:
            fout.write(line)
            continue
        values = line.strip().split(";")
        for j, value in enumerate(mag_rotated[i-1]):  # 15 values in float type
            index = j + 5
            values[index] = str(value)
        new_line = ";".join(values)
        fout.write(new_line + "\n")
```

Comment: Point 1 represents a one-time "up front" cost. Point 2 definitely addresses the decreasing performance aspect of the problem. I've tested this with tqdm and going to the method of appending a string drastically decreases the performance, by at least 315x.

Comment: Finishing in 20sec insteed of more than an hour! Thank you a lot! With 54500 it/s

Answer (score 1):

Like Obaskly pointed in item 2, appending the string over a million iterations is catastrophically slow.

```py
x = "a" * 50
s = ""
for _ in tqdm(range(1_000_000)):
    s += x
```

On my maching that starts around 5_000 it/s and steadily drops.

Since you tagged this python and csv, I recommend using the Python's standard csv module: it's only slightly slower than trying to manually parse (4 sec vs 1 sec to read/write 1M+ rows, on my machine), and makes the code simpler:

```py
import csv
from tqdm import tqdm

f_in = open("input.csv", newline="")
f_out = open("output.csv", "w", newline="")

reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=";")
writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=";")

writer.writerow(next(reader))  # transfer header

for i, row in tqdm(enumerate(reader)):
    row[5:20] = mag_rotated[i]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Because I manually iterated the header with `next(reader)`, when I start enumerating the rows in the for-loop it naturally starts with `i = 0`, which I believe will match up perfectly with your mag_rotated; no more `[i - 1]`.  Also, since you know you only need to change 15 fields starting at field 5, you can use Python's slice notation, `row[5:20] = mag_rotated[i]`, to update those fields; no more iterating over fields with an offset.

If you want to go the manually-parse-CSV route, you can use some of the techniqes from above to clean up the code you already have:

```py
DELIM = ";"

f_in = open("input.csv")
f_out = open("output.csv", "w")

f_out.write(next(f_in))

for i, line in tqdm(enumerate(f_in)):
    fields = line.strip().split(DELIM)
    fields[5:] = mag_rotated[i]
    f_out.write(DELIM.join(fields) + "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer and learning me csv module!! I choose other answer to greencheck only because it was a simple copy paste for me but it is same perf!